# Angular 2 - Call a function that exists outside of the current class

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to call a function that exists in **HomePage** class which is outside of the (class **Popover**) that I want to use the function on, I've already done some research, and I guess that I need to do something like dependency injection, I've tried to follow some tutorials but I was not lucky enough to solve the issue.

**Popover class:**

```
    @Component({
      template: `
        <div>
               <button ion-item *ngFor="let city of cities" (click)="switchToThisCity(city.cityName);close();">{{city.cityName | uppercase}}</button>
        </div>
      `
    })

        class MyPopover{
    static get parameters(){
      return [[Http], [ViewController]];
    }
     constructor(http, viewCtrl) {
      this.http    = http;
      this.viewCtrl = viewCtrl;
      //Async Call
      var getCities = new URLSearchParams();
      this.http.get('https://restApi.com/class/outlet', {headers: ParseHeaders}).subscribe(data => {
      this.cities = data.json().results;
      });
      ///
    }
     close() {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }
    switchToThisCity(currentCity){
      //I WANT TO CALL THIS FUNCTION WHICH EXISTS ON HomePage CLASS
      return getQueries(currentCity);
    }
  }
```

**HomePage Class:**

```
  @Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  })

        export class HomePage {
  static get parameters(){
      return [[NavController],[Http], [NavParams]];
    }

     // this.cartLength = this.cart.items.length;
    constructor() {}

   //I NEED TO USE THIS IN THE POPOVER CLASS

    getQueries(city){
    var cities = new URLSearchParams();
    cities.set('cityName', city);
   this.http.get('https://restApi.com/classes/citiesList', { search :   dishesParams, headers: ParseHeaders}).subscribe(data => {
   this.getCities = data.json().results;
   });
    }
 }
```

Comment: `export class MyPopover`, and HomePage constructor `constructor(public myPopover: MyPopover) {}`, then You can do for example `this.myPopover.close()`, off course You should `@import 'path-to-mypopover'`

Comment: you shouldn't do that!, create a service class something like `CityService` and move the function to the service, then you can call it from both the `hompage` class and `popover` class by injecting it

Comment: @daymosik, can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Service class

**cities.service**

```
@Injectable()
export class CitiesService {
  getQueries(city) {
    var cities = new URLSearchParams();
    cities.set('cityName', city);
    return this.http.get('https://restApi.com/classes/citiesList', {
      search: dishesParams,
      headers: ParseHeaders
    }) // here we return an observable so we can subscribe to it in our class
  }
```

and in Popover: (Same with homepage class)

```
export class MyPopover{ 
  constructor(private citiesService:CitiesService) {
  }

  // and this is how you use the function
  this.citiesService.getQueries().subscribe(data => {
   this.getCities = data.json().results;
   });
 }
```

**UPDATE** : have a look at this article: http://nicholasjohnson.com/blog/how-to-do-everything-in-angular2-using-es6/

> First up, anything is injectable in Angular, so PetService can be just a newable function.
>
> The Angular DI mechanism will automatically use it to create a
>   singleton that is local to the correct branch of the injector tree. If
>   you only have a root injector (made automatically by Angular 2 on
>   bootstrap), this will be a global singleton, just like Angular

the principle here is to create a service that handles the request and inject it, return an observable object and subscribe, then you can do whatever you want with the response...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I believe that's TypeScript; however, my app is written in ES6 and it's written on the question even, would you mind do an edit?

Answer (score 1):

I would extract the `getQueries` method into a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class QueryService {

  constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  static get parameters(){
    return [[Http]];
  }
}
```

and inject it into both components:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  providers: [ QueryService ]
})

export class HomePage {
  static get parameters(){
    return [[NavController],[NavParams], [QueryService];
  }

  constructor(nav, params, service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  getQueries(city){
    this.service.getQueries(city)...
  }
}
```

and the same in the `MyPopover` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've done everything on the correct way but I received an error `Missing class properties transform. while parsing file: ` I guess before `export class QueryService` I need to add `@Component` I am I right or it does not have a relationship?

Comment: You're welcome! In fact, for the `QueryService` class, you only need to add `@Injectable()` and not `@Component` since it's not a component...

Comment: You're right, but I am not able to run it and I receive in the terminal `Missing class properties transform. while parsing file: `

Comment: When parsing which file? ;-)

Comment: The same file that has the all the code, because all the 3 classes are located on the same file

Comment: I managed to avoid that error and solved it, but now what I can see is a blank page, any idea on what's causing that?